# Recursive function to format nested arrays to match against arrays of conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

Trying to write this eval function that takes in cases, loops through them and needs to check if it matches to a condition in a conditions array and returns true or false. I'm not sure how best to format the conditions array and run the matching on it. Conditions are nested, n-levels deep, so trying to get a recursive function.

```
console.log(cases.forEach(c => eval(formattedCondition, c.item)))

const conditions = [
 "OR",
 ["AND",["==","maker","airbus"],["==","name","A320"]],
 ["AND",[ "==", "maker","boeing"]],
 ["OR",["==","name","B767"]]
]

const cases = [
 {
   "item": {
    'maker': 'airbus',
    'name':"A320",
   }
 // should return true for this case
 },
 {
   "item": {
    'maker': 'embraer',
    'name':"e175",
   }
 // should return false for this case
 },
 {
   "item": {
    'maker': 'boeing',
   }
 // should return true for this case
 },
 {
   "item": {
    'name':"B767",
   }
// should return true for this case
 },
 {
   "item": {
    'maker': 'boeing',
    'name':"B777",
   }
 // should return false for this case
 },
]
```

Comment: Can you include _your_ implementations/tries at making the function, in the question?

Comment: well that's the things, I'm not sure how to format the conditions array which will influence what the search looks like

Comment: can you insert the wanted condition in javascript?

Comment: Like the `or`, `and`? yeah why not.

Comment: Why should the item with `'name':"B767"` return false? It matches with the third clause, and that should be enough. And why should the last case return false? The middle clause accepts any boeing without any condition on the name, so it should return true, no?

Comment: That's my mistake, should return true

Comment: why has this `["OR",["==","name","B767"]]` an `OR` operator, if there is only one operand?

Comment: well, the idea is it could have n number of levels in there

Comment: why `false` for the last case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take an approach without `eval` and use the data to build expressions with a function for checking with equal and some quantizers for `AND` and `OR`.

```js
const
    conditions = ["OR", ["AND", ["==", "maker", "airbus"], ["==", "name", "A320"]], ["AND", ["==", "maker", "boeing"]], ["OR", ["==", "name", "B767"]]],
    take = object => {
        const
            quantifiers = { AND: 'every', OR: 'some' },
            operators = { '==': (a, b) => a == b },
            evaluate = ([symbol, ...values]) => values.every(v => typeof v === 'string')
                ? operators[symbol](object[values[0]], values[1])
                : values[quantifiers[symbol]](evaluate);
        return evaluate;
    },
    cases = [
        { item: { maker: 'airbus', name: "A320" } },    // true
        { item: { maker: 'embraer', name: "e175" } },   // false
        { item: { maker: 'boeing' } },                  // true
        { item: { name: "B767" } },                     // true
        { item: { maker: 'boeing', name: "B777" } },    // true instead of false
    ],
    result = cases.map(({ item }) => take(item)(conditions));

console.log(result);
```